# Simplification of division of integral of standard normal distribution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, normal-distribution

I'm integrating two standard normal distributions and, for numerical problems, I would like to simplify the expresion below, since the only difference between the numerator and denominator is the upper limit, where $\theta$, $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$.

$$
\cfrac{\int _{-\infty }^{\theta}\!{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-{x}^{2}/2\,}}}{ \sqrt{2\,\pi }}}{dx}}{  \int _{-\infty }^{\beta}\!{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-{x}^{2}/2\,}}}{ \sqrt{2\,\pi }}}{dx}}.
$$

Any hint on how can I do this simplification?

Comment: First, it's not an equation.  A very simpler form:$\frac{\text{erf}\left(\frac{\theta }{\sqrt{2}}\right)+1}{\text{erf}\left(\frac{\beta }{\sqrt{2}}\right)+1}$

Comment: They are cdfs of standard normal distribution, so just $\Phi(\theta)/\Phi(\beta)$.

Comment: The set of real numbers is typically denoted $\mathbb{R}$ (`\mathbb{R}`) or $\mathbf{R}$ (`\mathbf{R}`) rather than $\mathcal{R}$.